# MinGW localtime_r works in one time zone, fails in another

Tags: c, mingw, unix-timestamp, epoch, localtime

I have the following file test.c:

```
 #define _POSIX_THREAD_SAFE_FUNCTIONS
 #include <time.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdint.h>
 #include <inttypes.h>

 int main(int argc,char**argv) {
    struct tm t1, t2, t3;
    time_t w1, w2, w3;
    memset(&t1,0,sizeof(struct tm));
    memset(&t2,0,sizeof(struct tm));
    memset(&t3,0,sizeof(struct tm));
    w1 = 0;
    errno = 0;
    localtime_r(&w1,&t1);
    printf("localtime_r: errno=%d\n",errno);
    errno = 0;
    w2 = mktime(&t1);
    printf("mktime: errno=%d result=%" PRId64 "\n",errno,((int64_t)w2));
    errno = 0;
    localtime_r(&w2,&t2);
    printf("localtime_r: errno=%d\n",errno);
    errno = 0;
    w3 = mktime(&t2);
    printf("mktime: errno=%d result=%" PRId64 "\n",errno,((int64_t)w3));
    errno = 0;
    localtime_r(&w3,&t3);
    printf("localtime_r: errno=%d\n",errno);
    printf("sizeof(time_t)=%" PRId64 "\n", ((int64_t)sizeof(time_t)));
    printf("W1=%" PRId64 " W2=%" PRId64 " W3=%" PRId64 "\n",((int64_t)w1),((int64_t)w2),((int64_t)w3));
    printf("Y1=%d Y2=%d Y3=%d\n",t1.tm_year,t2.tm_year,t3.tm_year);
    return 0;
 }
```

I compile it like this:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT=1 -o test.exe test.c
```

Note, `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc --version` reports `8.3-win32 20190406`
This is running in a Docker image of Ubuntu 19.04, using the MinGW version
that comes with Ubuntu 19.04 (it says version 6.0.0-3).

I have a Windows 10 VM (Version 1809 OS Build 17763.379).
By default, time zone is set to US Pacific Time (UTC-8).
I copy test.exe to this VM and run it there.

It prints:

```
localtime_r: errno=0
mktime: errno=0 result=0
localtime_r: errno=0
mktime: errno=0 result=0
localtime_r: errno=0
sizeof(time_t)=8
W1=0 W2=0 W3=0
Y1=69 Y2=69 Y3=69
```

That's the expected result. (At UTC midnight on 1 Jan 1970, it was still 1969 in UTC-8.)

I change the Windows time zone to UTC+10 (Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney).
Run it again. It prints:

```
localtime_r: errno=0
mktime: errno=0 result=47244640256
localtime_r: errno=22
mktime: errno=22 result=4294967295
localtime_r: errno=0
sizeof(time_t)=8
W1=0 W2=47244640256 W3=4294967295
Y1=70 Y2=-1 Y3=206
```

It seems the mktime() call is returning an invalid value in UTC+10 time zone, but returns the correct value of 0 in UTC-8 time zone.

Why does this code work in one timezone break in another?

Note, this is only a problem with `-D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT=1` to enable
64-bit time_t. If I leave that out, which means 32-bit time_t, then the code
works in both timezones. (But, 32-bit time_t is not a good idea, because it breaks in the year 2038, and that's less than twenty years away now.)

Comment: what if you use : `printf("W1=%lld W2=%lld W3=%lld\n",((long long) w1),((long long) w2),((long long) w3));` ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Thanks, you are right. `%d` is the wrong printf format to use because it is a 64-bit value. Going to update my question with adjusted code, the problem appears a bit different after doing this.

Comment: Perhaps [For portable code tzset(3) should be called before localtime_r()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime_r) applies?

Comment: @chux yes you are right about PRId64 for errno being overkill. I had a problem before I was using %d for 64-bit values, I went a bit overboard in remedying that. Changed it now.

Comment: As a matter of good investigation of why things may be failing, it would make sense to check the return value of the various `localtime_r()` calls as it "returns the value described, or NULL ... in case an error was detected."

Comment: @chux: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried adding `tzset()`, it made no difference. I also tried checking the return value of `localtime_r`. When it leaves errno as 0, it returns the expected pointer. When it sets errno to 22 (which I believe is EINVAL), the return value is NULL (for the second localtime_r call), or ((struct tm*)-1) (for the third one.)

Comment: Note: 47244640256 == 0xB00000000, certainly an error value.  I suspect problem is simplified to why does `w2 = mktime(&t1);` act wonky.  Might be illustrative to print the entire contents of `t1` before and after `mktime()`. Perhaps the prior `localtime_r(&w1,&t1);` put junk in `t1` - or is it `mktime(&t1);` that is errant?

Comment: Might it be that `mktime` returns a 32bit value (ie. `0x00000000`), but the caller expects a 64bit value (adding the `0xB` garbage) ? Ie. might this be an abi mismatch ? Or iow : was the library that implements `mktime` also built with `-D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT=1` or equivalent ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Thanks, that was it basically. When you `#define __MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT 1`, then `localtime_s` is defined as an inline function which calls `_localtime64_s`. And `#define _POSIX_THREAD_SAFE_FUNCTIONS` defines `localtime_r` as an inline function which calls `localtime_s`. However, `mktime` is still 32-bit. To get 64-bit `mktime`, you need to also `#define __MSVCRT_VERSION__ 0x1400` (or higher). Once you do that, `mktime` becomes an inline function which calls `_mktime64`. Before that, `mktime` is a normal function declaration which is linked to the legacy 32-bit `mktime`

Comment: So `#define __MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT 1` without `#define __MSVCRT_VERSION__ 0x1400` (or `-D` equivalent) gives you a `localtime_r` with 64-bit `time_t`, but a `mktime` with 32-bit `time_t`, which obviously won't work. (Or, I think even worse than that, the actual implementation of the `mktime` symbol is returning a 32-bit `time_t`, but the function declaration is for a 64-bit `time_t`, which is what causes the junk in the upper 32-bits.)

Comment: @SimonKissane : can you turn that information into an answer, so it serves others with the same issue ? Related : [Can I answer my own qustion ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Thanks, I just did that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out the cause of the problem. Sander De Dycker's suggestion, that `mktime` is returning a 32-bit value, is correct.

The problem is basically this: the MSVCRT defines three `mktime` functions: `_mktime32` for 32-bit time_t, `_mktime64` for 64-bit time_t, and `_mktime` which is a legacy alias for `_mktime32`.

[_mingw.h](https://github.com/mirror/mingw-w64/blob/v6.0.0/mingw-w64-headers/crt/_mingw.h.in#L369) does a `#define _USE_32BIT_TIME_T` in 32-bit code unless you `#define __MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT` to disable that. Once you have `#define __MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT`, then localtime_s is defined as an inline function which calls _localtime64_s. And `#define _POSIX_THREAD_SAFE_FUNCTIONS` defines `localtime_r` as an inline function which calls `localtime_s`. However, `mktime` is still 32-bit. To get 64-bit `mktime`, you need to also `#define __MSVCRT_VERSION__ 0x1400` (or higher). Once you do that, `mktime` becomes an inline function which calls `_mktime64`. Before that, `mktime` is a normal function declaration which is linked to the legacy 32-bit `mktime`.

So `#define __MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT 1` without `#define __MSVCRT_VERSION__ 0x1400` (or `-D` equivalent) gives you a `localtime_r` with 64-bit `time_t`, but a `mktime` with 32-bit `time_t`, which obviously won't work. Even worse than that, the actual implementation of the `mktime` symbol is returning a 32-bit `time_t`, but the function declaration is for a 64-bit `time_t`, which is what causes the junk in the upper 32-bits.

As to the difference behaviour in different time zones, I don't have a complete explanation for that, but I think the reason is likely as follows: when you have a function which actually returns a 32-bit value but is incorrectly being defined to return a 64-bit value, the upper 32-bits of the return value will hold random junk data left over from previous calculations. So, any difference in the previous calculations, or slightly different code paths, may result in different random junk. With a UTC-8 timezone, for whatever reason, the random junk is coincidentally zero, so the code (despite its incorrectness) actually works. With a UTC+10 timezone, the random junk turns out to be non-zero, which causes the rest of the code to stop working.